# C++ Inherited class function not working in class constructor, pass by reference string not changing

Tags: c++

I have a class named `Filesys` inheriting a class `Sdisk`

```
class Sdisk
{
    public:
    Sdisk(string disk_name, int number_of_blocks, int block_size);
    Sdisk(); //default constructor
    ...
    int getblock(int blocknumber, string& buffer); //buffer is changed but doesn't change when called by Filesys constructor

    private:
    string diskname;    //file name of software-disk
    int numberofblocks; //number of blocks on disk
    int blocksize;  //block size in bytes

};

class Filesys: public Sdisk
{
    public:
    Filesys(string disk_name, int number_of_blocks, int block_size);
    Filesys(); //default constructor
};
```

My constructor for `Fileys` is calling `getblock` from the `Sdisk` class and returns the correct value, but my string buffer does not change

```
Filesys::Filesys(string disk_name, int number_of_blocks, int block_size) {
    string buffer;
    int code = getblock(0, buffer);

    if (code == 0) {  //passes this so it is calling the function and returning a value
        cout << "Failed"; 
    }

    cout << buffer; //empty, buffer is not being changed by getblock
}
```

```
//returns the blocknumber called for and passes it by ref in buffer
int Sdisk::getblock(int blocknumber, string &buffer){
    ifstream file(diskname);
    int i = (blocknumber -1) * blocksize;
    int j = (blocknumber * blocksize) -1;
    int k = 0;
    char b;

    if (j > (blocksize * numberofblocks)) {
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }

    while (file >> noskipws >> b) {
        if ((k > i-1) && (k < j+1)) {
            buffer.push_back(b);
        }
        k++;
    }
    file.close();
    return 1;

}
```

This function works when it is called normally like

```
Sdisk disk1("test1",16,32);
string block3;
disk1.getblock(4, block3);
cout << block3; //correctly outputs what is being asked
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Both the `buffer.push_back(b);` and `return 1;` lines in `Sdisk::getblock` seem like *outstanding* places for breakpoints in a debugger to start breaking down where assumptions are going off the rails in the failure case.

Comment: @TheUltraempoleon You can try adding a `cout` before and after `buffer.push_back(b);` to see if something is actually added into the `buffer`. Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ctor of `Filesys` should forward the parameters to the base class ctor.
Something like:

```
Filesys::Filesys(string disk_name, int number_of_blocks, int block_size) 
     : Sdisk(disk_name, number_of_blocks, block_size) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise the members of the base class (e.g. diskname) are not initialized properly, and they are needed for `Sdisk::getblock` to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your function getBlock is called with blockNumber == 0

so these values will be weird.

```
int i = (blocknumber -1) * blocksize;
int j = (blocknumber * blocksize) -1;

i == -blocksize
j == -1
```

Then in your while loop, k will never be smaller than 0 (j + 1)

```
if ((k > i-1) && (k < j+1)) {
   buffer.push_back(b);
}
k++;
```